# execute a keyboard shortcut using apple script in automator

Tags: applescript

im using apple script in automator for the first time. i want the script to execute a keyboard shortcut within a previously launched application.

```
on run
activate application "MacCaption"
tell application "MacCaption"
    keystroke "x" using command down

end tell
```

Im getting Syntax Error expected end of line but found identifier on the word *using*.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `keystroke` has to go through System Events. Either:

```
tell app "System Events"
    keystroke "x" using command down
end tell
```

or

```
tell app "System Events"
    tell process "MacCaption"
        keystroke "x" using command down
    end tell
end tell
```

There's no real difference, but you need the System Events.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "x" using command down
```